# CodeIgniter Routes and Regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to create a route on CodeIgniter that matches 3 numbers followed by a hyphen followed by anything.  So far I have had zero luck.  I've tried the following:

```
$route['([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = 'product/index/$1';
$route['([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)'] = 'product/index/$1';
$route['(:num)-(:any)'] = 'product/index/$1';
$route['([0-9]{3})-(:any)'] = 'product/index/$1';
$route['(\d{3})-(:any)'] = 'product/index/$1';
```

And so on.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: why do you have 5 routes for the same page?

Answer (score 0):

*It looks like CodeIgniter does not use standard regex.*

*Try these:*

1. `(\d{3})\-.*`
2. `(\d{3})-.*`
3. `(\d{3})\-(:any)`
4. `(\d{3})-(:any)`

*One of them should work.*

*For more information see* http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be a parameter issue.
Perhaps you should try :

```
$route['([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = 'product/index/$1/$2';
```

Since you are catching 2 variables, it seems you should pass them both to the function.